# Extracting a specific list item using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a web scraper project using Python and Beautiful Soup. Please have look at the HTML code section which I am having trouble with. Since all the `<li>` items in the `<ul>` have the same class names for `<div>` and `<span>`, how can I extract the phone number i.e value of second `<span>` in the third `<li>` item?

I can extract the `<ul>` tag and its contents using `ad_soup.find("ul",{"class":"Menu"})`, but I do not know how to proceed after that. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<ul class="Menu">
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="name">Name:</span>
      <span class="value">....</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="name">Location:</span>
      <span class="value">....</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="name">Phone:</span>
      <span class="value">....</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If the phone is always the third element, you can use `phone = ad_soup.find_all("span", {'class':"name"})[2].getText() `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that the phone is always a third element, the following should help:

```
(ad_soup.find("ul",{"class":"Menu"}).
         find_all("li")[2].find("span", {"class": "value"}))
```

If you don't know that phone is always a third element, you can loop over all `li` and select the needed one:

```
[li.find("span", {"class": "value"}) 
 for li in ad_soup.find("ul",{"class": "Menu"}).find_all("li")
 if li.find("span", {"class": "name"}).string == "Phone:"]
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can extract all li's and find span in the resulting array like this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = """<ul class="Menu">
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="name">Name:</span>
      <span class="value">....</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="name">Location:</span>
      <span class="value">....</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="name">Phone:</span>
      <span class="value">ddd</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>"""

soup = bs(html)
tag = soup.findAll("li")[2].findAll("span")[1]

print tag
```